# Parsing XML with PHP with <![CDATA[

Tags: php, xml, json, parsing

I'm parsing XML with PHP using `simplexml_load_file`, then I `json_encode` and `json_decode` in order to get all the info as arrays:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('/var/www/darkglass/wp-content/themes/dark2/assets/xml/artists.xml');
$musicos = json_encode($xml);
$musicos = json_decode($musicos, true);
```

I'm having this problem where I want to add a HTML code inside the  tag, but it only works if I add a character before the `<![CDATA` like the example below:

This doesn't work:

```
<band><![CDATA[<a class="abandlink" href="#">Cannibal Corpse</a>]]></band>
```

This works:

```
<band>.<![CDATA[<a class="abandlink" href="#">Cannibal Corpse</a>]]></band>
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: What code are you running? What error is it giving?

Comment: this is how i'm getting the xml into array: [link](http://pastebin.com/xrF9jvPJ)

If I don't add the "." or any other character in front of <![CDATA it simply doesnt show the content

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LIBXML_NOCDATA` option:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('artists.xml', 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I found a workaround to this problem, 
I just added `substr`, `$band = substr($band, 1);` to the variable, so it removes the first character of the variable, and it works.